# Virtual Host based on name and port

Tags: apache-2.2

I wish to create a several number of virtual hosts which I want to access them via port and name. For example, I have two websites, one `http://carrito:8080` and `http://pagina:80.` At first glance it works, but when I write on the browser `http://pagina:8080`, it sends me to the carrito web page. I want Apache to deny me  access to the website instead of redirecting me to the other. How can I accomplish this?

My configuration on the ports.conf is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
#############
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080
```

And the virtual host configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@carrito.com
ServerName  carrito.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/carrito
<Directory /var/www/carrito>
  Options None
  Order deny,allow
  allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuration of the other virtual hosts are ver similar, except for their respective data of name, directory etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a dummy website and place it's definition first in the configuration file.